# Why chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener Function Runs Multiple Times?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to show multiple notifications at the same time. If i run NotificationBasic function multiple times i the loop. I get the notifications bottom right of the screen with no problem. But if i clicked to the notification button one time it acts as if i clicked several times and logs a bunch of BUTTON CLİCKED on console. On the other hand, IDS ARE EQUAL are not shown on anywhere.

If i clicked on the notification button i want to open index.html page.

```
function NotificationBasic(NotificationTitle, NotificationMessage, href){
    var options = {
        type: "basic",
        title: NotificationTitle,
        message: NotificationMessage,
        iconUrl: "icon.png",
        contextMessage: "Notification",
        buttons: [{
            title: "Go to the topic-->"
        }]
    };
    chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(notifId){
        console.log("BUTTON CLİCKED");
        console.log("notifId: "+notifId);
        console.log("myNotificationID: "+myNotificationID);
        if(notifId == myNotificationID){
            console.log("IDS ARE EQUAL");
            window.open("/index.html"); 
        }      
    });
    chrome.notifications.create(options, function(id){
        myNotificationID = id;
    });
}

    for(let i = 0; i<new_ids.length; i++){
        let topic_id = ids.indexOf(new_ids[i]);
        new_topics[i] = messages[topic_id];
        if((messages[topic_id][1].includes("?day=")==false)){
        NotificationBasic(messages[topic_id][0], 'New topic', messages[topic_id][1]);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your function, `chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(...)` is executed for many times, so many lines get logged.

Comment: How can i show multiple notifications at the same time without looping it?

Comment: You may call `notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener` outside the loop, and call `notifications.create` in the loop